# How to export a confluence page as PDF in Jenkins job?

Tags: shell, jenkins, confluence

I'm wrinting a Jenkins job with the help of shell script to export a page in Confluence as PDF and store it as output after the build.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally foud a solution :

```
curl -D- -u user:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "<confluence_ url>/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=123456789" > curl_ouput.txt
## Read response and extract URL for downloading file
FILE_LOCATION=$(grep "Location: " curl_ouput.txt | sed 's/Location: //g')
## Remove newline character at the end of the url
FILE_LOCATION=${FILE_LOCATION%?}
## Download PDF file
curl -D- -u user:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8" <confluence_url>${FILE_LOCATION} --output fileName.pdf
rm -f curl_ouput.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wkhtmltopdf to perform the conversion from html to pdf.

You can also convert an existing website to PDF

```
$wkhtmltopdf  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin#space-menu-link-content demo.pdf
```

Note: technically Google Chrome's rendering engine is Blink, which is a fork of Webkit. There is >90% of common code between Blink and Webkit, so you should get a similar result.

if your getting error

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

try to install

> sudo apt-get install xvfb

and then try this

```
 xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin#space-menu-link-content demo.pdf
```

Then you will find this pdf file as output in jenkins workspace.